# Printing on Hahnemühle Photo Rag 308 and 500 gsm with Canon PIXMA PRO-100

Tags: printing, prints, paper

I am considering to purchase the Canon PIXMA PRO-100 and would like to use the Hahnemühle Photo Rag 308 and 500 gsm for my primary media.  I've read a few reviews where users claim that this particular printer tends to jam up when really thick media is used.  Has anyone used the Photo Rag 308 and 500 gsm or a similar art paper with this printer?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used them, but the Canon user manual for the Pro-100 states:

> **Paper Weight / Thickness**
>
> You can use paper in the following weight ranges.
>
> rear tray: From 17 to 28 lb (64 to 105 g /m2) (plain paper except for Canon genuine paper)
>
> - You can use non-Canon genuine specialty paper that is up to 53 lb (200 g /m2).
>
> Do not use heavier or lighter paper (except for Canon genuine paper), as it could jam in the printer.
>
> manual feed tray: From 4 to 23.6 mil (0.1 to 0.6 mm) (up to 93 lb (350 g /m2))
>
> Do not use paper thicker or heavier than this, as it could jam in the printer.

So, the Pro-100's rear tray can only take up to 200 gsm, and the manual feed slot can take from 0.1 to 0.6mm thickness and up to 350 gsm.

Hahnemühle's website gives the following thicknesses for their Photo Rag paper:

> - 308 gsm: thickness: 0,48mm  (18 mil)
> - 500 gsm: thickness: 0,80mm  (31 mil)

So, it looks like, from the specs, that the 308 gsm Photo Rag is within specs for use with the Pro-100's manual feed tray (but not the rear tray), and that the 500 gsm is too thick and too heavy and could cause a jam.

Practical experience may be different.